# Fastest way to compute determinants over (lists of) machine precision numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

The below code is a code snippet of a larger project of mine. The project is mostly optimised but this part is not. I'm struggling to improve it, the code takes a really long time to evaluate for what it does: it calculates a determinant of an $L\times L$ matrix of real variables. The variables appear to be of Machine precision, and so one would not expect the calculation to take too long. Regardless, the evaluation of the below matrix takes a whopping 21 seconds on my MacBook, and `ParallelTable` actually improves the times in this case (feel free to take it out if it doesn't for you). I'd like to better get the hang of computing determinants in this way, and hope someone could give me some pointers to optimise the below calculations.

```
UMatrix[j_Integer, k_Integer, 
  InteractionStrength_Real, {BraRoots_List, KetRoots_List}] := 
 I*((Indexed[BraRoots, j] - 
      Indexed[KetRoots, j])/(V[j, 
       InteractionStrength, {BraRoots, KetRoots}] - 
      V[j, -InteractionStrength, {BraRoots, KetRoots}]))*
  Exp[Sum[Log[Indexed[KetRoots, l] - Indexed[BraRoots, j]] - 
     Log[Indexed[BraRoots, l] - Indexed[BraRoots, j]], {l, 
     DeleteCases[Range@Length@KetRoots, j]}]]*(K[
     Indexed[BraRoots, j] - Indexed[BraRoots, k], 
     InteractionStrength] - 
    K[LambdaP - Indexed[BraRoots, k], InteractionStrength])

V[j_Integer, 
   InteractionStrength_Real, {BraRoots_List, KetRoots_List}] := 
  Product[(Indexed[KetRoots, l] - Indexed[BraRoots, j] + 
      I*InteractionStrength)/(Indexed[BraRoots, l] - 
      Indexed[BraRoots, j] + I*InteractionStrength), {l, 
    Range@Length@BraRoots}];

K[\[Lambda]_, InteractionStrength_] := 
  2.*InteractionStrength/(\[Lambda]^2 + InteractionStrength^2);

SlavnovPre[{BraRoots_List, KetRoots_List}, {InteractionStrength_Real, 
    SystemSize_Integer}] := Block[{UMatrixS, LogChi},

   UMatrixS[j_Integer, k_Integer] := 
    UMatrix[j, k, InteractionStrength, {BraRoots, KetRoots}];

   LogChi = 
    Log[Det[IdentityMatrix[Length@BraRoots] + 
       ParallelTable[
        UMatrixS[j, k], {j, Range@Length@BraRoots}, {k, 
         Range@Length@BraRoots}]]]

   ];

c = 40.;
L = 200;
LambdaP = 5.;

CurrentBraList = Sort@RandomReal[{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, L];
CurrentKetList = Sort@RandomReal[{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, L];

SlavnovPre[{CurrentBraList, CurrentKetList}, {c, 
   L}]  //  AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: The bottleneck here is not to compute the determinant of a matrix; it is about computing the enties of the matrix. My suggestion: Learn how to use `Compile`.

Comment: FWIW: `K[]` is a built-in function, so please do not use it for your function.

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon Cheers, I will change that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of optimization opportunities. For starters, here a way to compute all relevant values of `V` to 12 digits accuracy in one go -- and 100 times faster:

```
c = 40.;
L = 200;
a = Sort@RandomReal[{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, L];
b = Sort@RandomReal[{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, L];

Vvector = Table[V[j, c, {a, b}], {j, 1, L}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Vvectorfast = With[{X = KroneckerProduct[ConstantArray[-1., L], a]},
     Exp@Subtract[
       Total@Log@Plus[KroneckerProduct[b, ConstantArray[1., L]], X, I*c],
       Total@Log@Plus[KroneckerProduct[a, ConstantArray[1., L]], X, I*c]
       ]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[(Vvectorfast/Vvector - 1)]]
```

> 0.177699
>
> 0.001685
>
> 1.11182*10^-12

## Edit

Finally, I have been able to come up with a faster version of to compute the matrix `U`:

```
myUMatrix[c_, {a_, b_}, LambdaP_] := 
 Module[{X, bminusa, aminusa, v1, v2, v, u, w, L},
  L = Length[b];
  X = ConstantArray[-a, L];
  bminusa = KroneckerProduct[b, ConstantArray[1., L]] + X;
  aminusa = KroneckerProduct[a, ConstantArray[1., L]] + X;
  v1 = Exp[Subtract[Total@Log[bminusa + I c], Total@Log[aminusa + I c]]];
  v2 = Exp[Subtract[Total@Log[bminusa - I c], Total@Log[aminusa - I c]]];
  v = I Divide[Subtract[a, b], Subtract[v1, v2]];
  u = Exp[
    ConstantArray[1., L].Subtract[
      Log[bminusa + DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[1. - Diagonal[bminusa]]]],
      Log[aminusa + IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]]]
    ];
  w = Subtract[K[aminusa, c], ConstantArray[K[Subtract[LambdaP, a], c], L]];
  u v w
  ]
```

Test:

```
U = Table[UMatrix[j, k, c, {a, b}], {j, 1, L}, {k, 1, L}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
myU = myUMatrix[c, {a, b}, LambdaP]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[myU/U - 1]]
```

> 106.463
>
> 0.091512
>
> 1.29108*10^-12

So with precision of 12 digits, this is more than 1000 times faster. The time for actually calculating the desired determinant can be neglected:

```
Log[Det[myU + IdentityMatrix[L]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000947, 346.127 + 3.14159 I}

Comment: Very nice solution. Perhaps one more optimisation would be to use: `v2 = Conjugate[v1]` but the timing improvements will be incremental at best. Many thanks!:)

Comment: Thank you. Good point. `v = 0.5 Divide[Subtract[a, b], 
    Im[Exp[Subtract[Total@Log[bminusa + I c], 
       Total@Log[aminusa + I c]]]]];` should do even better. But it is not. The bulk computation is for the $L \times L$-matrices, not here.

Comment: Small extra question: How do I reproduce these results for this "conditional product" when there is an imaginary part in the product? The results are reproduced *almost* exactly for for example: `(Indexed[a,l]-Indexed[a,m] + I*c)/(Indexed[a,l]-Indexed[a,m])`, but the imaginary parts don't match the explicit expression. How is expression `u` calculated inside `myU`?

Comment: Hmmm. The proplem with `(Indexed[a,l]-Indexed[a,m])` is that it might lie on the branch cut locus of _Mathematica's_ `Log` function. And of course, division by zero might occur for diagonal elements of `aminusa`... But I have to say that I do not understand your question.

Comment: Your answer above explicitly calculates the double product : $\prod_{m\neq \ell}(b_\ell-a_m)/(a_{\ell} - a_{m})$.I'm interested also in the product: $\prod_{m\neq \ell}(a_{\ell} - a_{m} + I*c)/(a_{\ell} - a_{m})$, which does not give the same precision when calculated using the technique above. I must admit I am not sure what is happening in the calculation of `u`, so I am trying to get a better understanding of it so I can apply it to this other product as well.

Comment: Hm. You may try something like `A = (1. + I c/(aminusa + IdentityMatrix[L]));
Do[A[[j, j]] = 1., {j, 1, L}];
Times @@@ A`. `Times @@@ ` is surprisingly fast. Note also that the resulting number may be super large so that the absolute errors are not meaningful. You should check _relative_ errors instead.

Comment: That solved it! I have a new question about the above material; I will post a separate question. Thank you for your assistance so far

Comment: You're welcome!